# Last Accessed Time of any file in Android

Tags: android

`file.lastModified()` returns the last modified date. File does not seem to have any method to fetch lastAccessed date. Is there a way to programmatically fetch the last accessed date/time of any file in android ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the last access time using [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [`lstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html). The two methods, [`android.system.Os.stat(String path)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#stat(java.lang.String)) and [`android.system.Os.lstat(String path)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#lstat(java.lang.String)), were made public in Android 5.0. On previous Android versions you will need to use reflection or run a command in a shell.

### Usage:

**Android 5.0+**

```
long lastAccessTime = Os.lstat(file.getAbsolutePath()).st_atime;
```

**Using reflection before Android 5.0**

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore");
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("os");
if (!field.isAccessible()) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
}
Object os = field.get(null);

Method method = os.getClass().getMethod("lstat", String.class);
Object lstat = method.invoke(os, file.getAbsolutePath());

field = lstat.getClass().getDeclaredField("st_atime");
if (!field.isAccessible()) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
}
long lastAccessTime = field.getLong(lstat);
```

---

### Note:

I don't think last access time is used on Android. From the `java.nio` documentation:

> If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time of last access then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

I tested changing the last access time using the following command:

```
touch -a [PATH]
```

This did change the last access time when I ran the command as the root user. However, I don't think the last accessed time is updated/used on Android.

Comment: "This did change the last access time when I ran the command as the root user. However, I don't think the last accessed time is updated/used on Android" - Do you mean to imply that lastAccessTime does not make any sense to Android as it does not support this time stamp ?

Comment: Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore") is resolving to libcore.io.BlockGuardOs. So, os.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("lstat", String.class); is throwing - NoSuchMethodException: lstat [class java.lang.String]. Is Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore") resolving to expected value ?

Comment: `Os` is an `interface` and `libcore.io.BlockGuardOs` is expected. After reading the old source code, it looks like `lstat` is implemented in `ForwardingOs`. Just change `getDeclaredMethod` to `getMethod`. I don't think lastAccessTime is used in Android, although supported.

Comment: "I don't think lastAccessTime is used in Android, although supported" - were you implying that ANdroid does not return me the lastAccessedTime, but either created or last modified ?

Comment: Right. At least on my device the lastAccessTime returns the last modified time. I can change it manually using `touch -a`.

Comment: Most android devices don't even support setLastModified. I must find some other way. Thank you Jared.

Answer (score -1):

lastModified ()

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

public class FileExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      File f = null;
      String path;
      long millisec;
      boolean bool = false;

      try{      
         f = new File("c:/demo.txt");

         bool = f.exists();

         if(bool)
         {
            millisec = f.lastModified();

            // date and time
            Date dt = new Date(millisec);

            // path
            path = f.getPath();

            System.out.print(path+" last modified at: "+dt);
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for lastAccessedTime and not lastModified. Please refer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
javaxt.io.File file = new javaxt.io.File("file-path");
file.getLastAccessTime();
```

Comment: Did you try this in Android? 
Doesn't seem so.