# file.setLastModified does not work in Android

Tags: android, file, last-modified, lastaccesstime

I am trying to achieve lastAccessedTime of a File in Android, for which I tried the following 2 methods:

1. Using `lstat` as described of its use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409730/last-accessed-time-of-any-file-in-android).

But Android does not use lastAccessedTime, during which either lastModified/fileCreation time is returned.

2. Using `file.setLastModified`, but Android is returning false on performing `setLastModified` over a `file`.

   ```
   long now = new Date().getTime()
   boolean success = file.setLastModified(now)
   ```

Few threads in stackoverflow described this bug with Android, but all of them are quite old. Did Android resolve this known issue in later versions ? or is there and other solution for fetching lastAccessedTime of a file ?

3. The ugly fix as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18624).

   ```
   RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
   long length = raf.length();
   raf.setLength(length + 1);
   raf.setLength(length);
   raf.close();
   ```

I'm afraid if this would corrupt any of the files.

Would be grateful for any help.