# Find files not accessed in last x days on android

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk

I've an android app that writes files to the disk frequently.
I want to write a cleanup module that would find files that are not accessed in last x days and report/clean them up.

Since the filesystem would generally be noatime.
I was wondering what would be a nice design to go ahead with this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, but I found out that android doesnt have implemented "time of last access", so I created database where I save access time when user opens the file. Maybe you can use something similar if user is opening files through your app.

Comment: For my use, going back and tracking every file would be difficult. Besides I'm looking for a solution on cleaning up already exising files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you need using the `stat` command - you can look here for an example: [Last Accessed Time of any file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409730/last-accessed-time-of-any-file-in-android)

Comment: I think that doesn't work on filesystems where no access time is stored.